# prevent children from returning false

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make a menu with a submenu and I want the list point be just clickable once until the user gets to the next one.

I tried it with return false, but in this case the  tags are not clickable anymore.

```
<div id="navigation">
<ul>
    <li>corsets</li>
    <li class="active">news
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.php">blablaba</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.php">blubbblubb</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>person
        <ul>
            <li><a href="person.php">blablaba</a></li>
            <li><a href="person.php">blubbblubb</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>contact</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

and the javascript:

```
$("#navigation li").click(function(evt){

    if($(this).hasClass("active")) {
        return false;
    }

    $(this).addClass('active'); 
});
```

if the user clicks the next menu point, the one before is clickable again of course, I remove the `.active` in a later function. This is just a snippet...

Comment: sorry, it was a snippet from the original code... of course the main list points should be the main selector... :)

Answer (score 0):

This may seem silly and simple but you can use:

```
$('#navigation li').click(function(evt) {
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

That will add it if it isn't there and remove it if it is.  You can also use:

```
$(this).html($(this).text);
```

If you want to remove the hyperlink (assuming your formatting isn't based around them, in which case nevermind).

Comment: What will be added and removed ?

Comment: It will add/remove the "active" class whenever the link is clicked.  I would even go so far as to say not even to use that and make it removeClass() on all the other links and then specifically addClass() to $(this).  That will keep the links from lingering after moving on to another menu.

Comment: Yes, this would work, BUT it is important, that the active <li> tag is not clickable anymore but the <a> tags are...

Comment: Are you trying to make a tree/hierarchy?

Comment: you're welcome!  come back here and let me know if you get stuck again.  no coder left behind.

Comment: Damn... it doesn´t work... or I am too s... for that... I matched it now to my original one on: test.kpunktwerk.com 

sorry for my weird code.... :/ maybe you have 5 minutes to take a look...

Comment: It seems like the site (aside from the links not actually going anywhere) is working like it should.  I also have been up 46 hours now so I think I'm gonna get some sleep but I'll check back later if you can clarify the end goal for me.

Comment: thanks a lot.... yes and no... the link: the Spike goes to a nother page... :) I will link all off them to this subpage to make it more clear... thanks a lot... !!